# Which validation method is better?

Tags: javascript

Is it better to validate user input using this method

```
if (obj == null) {
   // detects null and undefined
   // exit the function, input not validated
}
```

or this method

```
if (!obj) {
    // detects false, 0, -0, '', null, undefined, NaN
    // exit the function, input not validated
}
```

In this particular case, obj represents an array to be looped through.

I'm having difficulty deciding which method to use.

Comment: It all depends on your use case and preference. If you need to be strict, `Array.isArray()` would be a good choice. Else it is up to your preference.

Comment: They are *different*. Is "" allowed as user input?

Comment: Google for javascript strict equals and close this question

Comment: @AndyRay It's not strict equality (`===`) in either case. The OP also acknowledges that the conditionals match different values (which also makes this more of a subjective question ..)

Comment: you can loop through an empty string. It has a length property. arrays are truthy and empty arrays will fail both tests. google. close.

Comment: @stack_temp: How can it "user input" and "an array"? I've only seen users input strings somewhere, so what do you mean by "represent" (have you parsed it already)?

Comment: Neither is __better__; you need to validate that the object conforms to whatever rules you've set for it.

Comment: What does that even mean?

Comment: Ok? But you can't "loop through" a boolean either.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "loop through."

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33936/discussion-between-mathletics-and-stack-temp)

Comment: Rollbacked. Do not remove your post this way.

Comment: What @soon said; don't do that again, please.

Comment: `obj == null` will filter out all objects which can not be looped through.

Comment: it detects null and undefined which are the only object instances that are guaranteed not to have properties...try reading a book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to be honest, since javascript is interpreted anyway, the overhead of the operation is huge compared to actually evaluating it, so it doesn't matter. You can always test by doing it a million times in a loop and timing which is faster.

Answer (score 1):

You've described the differences. So it's up to you - do you want `false` or `''` to pass your conditional or not?

For an array, you may want to consider:

```
if (obj && obj.length) {
    // Your array is not null, and has items.
}
```

Comment: @stack_temp If you're worried that `length` might give you a non-number, sure. If you go this route, and still want to validate that it's not an empty array, you'd have to go a step further with `(obj && obj.length && obj.length === +obj.length)`. You could take it another step further and ensure that the type is an array. Personally, I'd stick with simplicity - knowing that the length is "truthy" would be good enough for me.